# Deal with padding on text with Safari/Chrome/FF

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I'm trying to understand how I have different padding on all browser.
Here is a screenshot for `Safari` `Chrome` and `Firefox` with the exact same code :

```
nav{
    position:relative;
    text-align:right;
    float:right;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
nav ul li{
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:.4em;
   }
nav ul li a{
   position:relative; 
   padding:2px;
   display:inline-block;
   background:red;
   line-height:1;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
    color:#e0e0e0;
}
```

[image: Menu on Safari, Chrome and Firefox]

The result:

- on Safari : 2px 3px 5px 2px
- on Chrome : 4px 1px 2px 1px
- on Firefox : 5px 2px 1px 2px

There is a solution for that ?

Comment: And your results really are the padding of the `a` element or something else, like the `ul` or `li`? Could you provide the CSS for your `ul` and `li` as well?

Comment: I update my code, but this problem appear everywhere in my website, not only on this li / a

Comment: The developer tools in your browser can tell you [where the padding comes from](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/170115/5qpn9dib.png). Possibly something overrides your style.

Comment: Yep I know, but nothing overrides. And the most wired is that a default "sans-serif" font family have the same problem.

Comment: Maybe because I've got an "old" mac book with a non retina screen, and using **em** for fonts create bugs …

Comment: @Alex I don't get any extra padding from your code. all browser give the same result. you can test on your site by adding this on your css *{padding:0; margin:0;}  [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/b7hgasLv/4/ ]

Comment: So I imagine the problem is my font, I will have to deal with that

Answer (score 0):

Add css3 box sizing to `nav ul li a`. Try it hope it will fix the issue.

```
nav ul li a {
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: Already have that on `*{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;}`

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the User Agent Stylesheet. Add set the padding you want with CSS, BUT don't forget to add !important! So it has to look something like this:
    
        nav ul li a{
           position: relative; 
           padding: 2px !important;
           display: inline-block;
           background-color: red;
           line-height: 1;
        }

Comment: Nope change nothing, I think is the type and each browser decode the type differently